# The importance of being real

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\Sigma$ be a collection of holomorphic, one-to-one function from some simply connected region $\Omega$, which map $\Omega$ into the open unit disc $U$.

Fix $z_0 \in \Omega$ and put $$\eta = \sup\{|\psi'(z_0)|:\psi \in \Sigma\}$$
We want to find a function $h \in \Sigma$ such that $h'(z_0) = \eta$.

Now, before doing that, shouldn't we first make sure that $\eta < \infty$? 
But I don't know how to prove it. Of course $|\psi'(z_0)| < \infty$ for every $\psi \in \Sigma$ since they are holomorphic,but that does not suffice, does it?

Can somebody help me clear out this point?

P.S. As someone may have recognized,it's the final part of the proof of the Riemann Mapping theorem from "Real and Complex Analysis", by Rudin

Comment: I don't have the book at hand, so I can't check. Are you sure that $\Sigma$ is completely arbitrary? Otherwise one can just consider as $\Omega$ the unit disk $z_0=0$ and $\psi_n(z)=(z+1)^n$, so $\psi_n'(0)=n$ and the supremum is infinity.

Comment: @egreg Of course. I'm sorry, I forgot to add that the functions map $\Omega$ into the open unit disc $U$. Edited :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|h(z)| < 1$ for all $h \in \Sigma$ and all $z \in \Omega$, so $\Sigma$
is *uniformly bounded*.

[Montel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel's_theorem) states
that a uniformly bounded family is *normal*, i.e. every sequence of
members of $\Sigma$ contains a subsequence which converges uniformly on 
compact subsets of $\Omega$. (Theorem 14.6 in my edition of Rudin.)

Now from the definition of $\eta$ it follows that there is a sequence
$(h_n)$ in $\Sigma$ such that $|h_n'(z_0)| \to \eta $.
Since $\Sigma$ is normal, this sequence has a subsequence $(h_{n_k})$
which converges uniformly on compact subsets to a holomorphic
function $H$.

Then $h_{n_k}' \to H'$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$, and in particular $|h_{n_k}'(z_0)| \to |H'(z_0|$ and therefore $\eta = |H(z_0| <\infty $.

(The proof in Rudin's book then continues to show that this $H$ actually *is* a
conformal mapping from $\Omega$ onto the unit disk.)

Comment: thanks! Why does it follow from the definition that there is a sequence $h_n$ in $\Sigma$ such that $|h'_n(z_0)| \to \eta$? Is this a property of the supremum?

Comment: @Ant: Yes. The supremum is the least upper bound, therefore there must be values arbitrary close to it.

Comment: yes :) It is what i thought, although I'd like to see a formal proof (that is, going from "the infimum of the upper bounds" to "then there is a sequence of values arbitrarily close to it")

Comment: @Ant: Choose any strictly  increasing sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers with $x_n \to \eta$. (E.g. $x_n = \eta - 1/n$ if $\eta$ is finite, or $x_n = n$ if $\eta = \infty$.) Then for each $n$, $x_n < \eta$ is *not* an upper bound of the set $ \{|\psi'(z_0)|:\psi \in \Sigma \}$, so there must be a $h_n \in \Sigma$ such that $|h_n'(z_0)| > x_n$.

Comment: @Ant: Does that help? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: thank you you've been very helpful :-) Sorry for the late reply ;)